# How do I invite only work accounts to my azure active directory?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a B2B AAD tenant I am using for authentication for my app, and inviting users to it using Microsoft graph invitation API. Unfortunately some users have either both a work and personal account, or just a personal account linked to the email, and there doesn't seem to be any way I can restrict the invitation to their work account (or in the case of just a personal account, force the creation of a shadow tenant).

Is it possible to only invite work accounts? Or force users to sign in with a work account?

Comment: You could use policies to allow or deny domains. Read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/allow-deny-list

Comment: We already block domains, the problem is an email address on a custom domain can have a work account or a personal account, or both.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to specify this requirement when sending an invite.
Would be a good parameter to have though.

When signing in, you can force the user to use a work/school account by adding `msa_fed=0` to the URL.
If you are using the v2.0 endpoint, you can use the `organizations` endpoint instead of `common`.

Note that both of these rely on setting a URL parameter which the user could easily manipulate.
So you would probably want to also check on the app side that the tenant id is not the MS account tenant id. (9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad)

Comment: I am using my own tenant for B2B (so can't use organizations), but blocking sign-ins will just block the account the have already accepted the invitation on.